# list with initial-element are start from 99 to 0 in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Function that takes a positive number and creates a list of all numbers between 0 (included) and the number passed as an argument (excluded). By default, it's 100

```
(defun list-numbers (&optional (n 100))
  (mapcar #'abs (make-list n :initial-element (- n 1))))
```

if you want to see the result https://ideone.com/Jbz5u3

> (99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99
>   99 99 99  99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99
>   99 99 99 99 99 99  99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99
>   99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99  99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99
>   99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99)

but my goal is create a simple list that initial-element are started with values ​​from 99 to 0

> (99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91 90 89 88 87 86.... 
>     9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0)

Comment: `make-list` is an ordinary function; the `(- n 1)` expression is an ordinary argument expression which gets reduced to a single value that is passed into `make-list`; in this case `99`. `make-list` creates a list filled with repetitions of this initial value. Probably it's most often used for filling a list with zeros, `nil` or perhaps `t`.

Comment: you right, thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CL-USER 160 > (loop for i from 99 downto 0 collect i)
(99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91 90 89 88 87 86 85 84 83 82 81 80 79 78 77 76 75 74 73 72 71 70 69 68 67 66 65 64 63 62 61 60 59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 50 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41 40 39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0)
```

or

```
CL-USER 167 > (do* ((i      0        (+ i 1))
                    (result (list i) (cons i result)))
                   ((= i 99) result))
(99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91 90 89 88 87 86 85 84 83 82 81 80 79 78 77 76 75 74 73 72 71 70 69 68 67 66 65 64 63 62 61 60 59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 50 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41 40 39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0)
```

Comment: Thanks @Rainer, in fact, I don´t need to use make-list, your answer is that I need and maybe you can help me in other question like [find "T" position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59040384/find-the-position-of-an-atom-in-list) and this [swap this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022738/shuffle-list-without-duplicate-number-in-lisp)

Comment: see the result that all implementation with your answer [see the result](https://ideone.com/ATJNj5) and I need to swap or shuffle with no repetition, [see the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022738/shuffle-list-without-duplicate-number-in-lisp)